# HDMI Monitor issue t480s and 18.04

Tags: 18.04, display, hdmi

I have a new Lenovo t480s on to which I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.

When I connect an external secondary monitor, A Philips 278E, it is detected and appears in the settings pane but I cannot seem to get it to actually transmit an image to it.

xrander outputs the following:

```
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y 
axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  74.97    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00    50.00    50.00  
   720x480       60.00    60.00    59.94    59.94    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Which confuses me as I only have a single HDMI port. Is there a physical issue with the port or could something else be causing this?

Comment: Try the BIOS/UEFI settings for selecting the discrete GPU, sometimes the external monitor is only available when that is done.

Comment: I can't find anything like a setting of that kind in the bios for the T480s. Could you explain in more detail what I am looking for?

Comment: My W520 under the display has a selector for GPU:1)Integrated, 2)Discrete, or 3)Optimus  and under that is an enable/disable for GPU selection. I use Optimus/enable  which I think was the same setting for when I had an external monitor. Integrated did not allow an external monitor (on the hdmi/dvi port).

Comment: Pretty sure the t480s only has integrated graphics. But why would it have a HDMI port that cannot work...